# Unit Tests not running because "Could not load file or assembly System.IO" exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

Essentially I have a project with 3 unit tests projects. Total of approx 400 unit tests.

However I am unable to Run All/Debug All unit tests using Visual Studio 2019. I have to right click each project and click run to execute each unit test project.

When I try to Run All I get the blue "not run" symbol next to the tests in the Test Explorer. It only seems to be these projects, other unit tests in different solutions work/personal run fine.

Digging into Output > Tests I find the following helpful message:

`[05/06/2020 12:06:23.884 PM] ---------- Run started ---------- An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [05/06/2020 12:06:27.720 PM] ========== Run finished: 0 tests run (0:00:03.7595631) ==========`

I have tried lots of different approaches to fix this, including:

- Rebuilt and Cleaned out solution artifacts using VS2019 and dnt tools clean (https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT)
- Updating mstest nuget packages
- Deleting .vs, packages, TestResults and %temp% VS folders
- Tried this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/25466/view.html
- Switched to nuget references instead of project ref
- Re-cloned repo
- The only thing I have found that seems to do the job is scatter [DeploymentItem(@"System.IO.dll")] on some of the unit tests.

Next step is either re-installing Visual Studio, or rebuild the laptop.

I am using latest Visual Studio 2019.

Help!

**---------------------- Update ----------------------**

This issue seems to only occur on Tests that have the [DeploymentItem] attribute on top of the class. Not sure if there is anything in that?

Comment: Have a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/295)

Comment: Rebuild Solution helps me in similar situations.

Comment: Thank you both. 

@AlexanderPetrov rebuild is my usual goto. the list of what I have tried so far is above.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your .net version in the test project, had the same issue with framework 462, once moved to framework 48 everything works perfect.

Since running tests with DeploymentItem it executes them from separate folder, and looks like old .net have some issues copying some dlls.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go when I get a chance and let you know how I get on!!